# How to conduct parametric bootstrapping in R?

Tags: r, for-loop, glm

I am working with the `orings` data set in the `faraway` package in `R`. I have written the following grouped binomial model:

```
orings_model <- glm(cbind(damage, 6-damage) ~ temp, family = binomial, data = orings)
summary(orings_model)
```

I then constructed the Chi-Square test statistic and calculated the p-value:

```
pchisq(orings_model$null.deviance, orings_model$df.null,lower=FALSE)
```

First, I would like to generate data under the null distribution for this test statistic using `rbinom` with the average proportion of damaged o-rings (i.e., the variable "damage"). Second, I would like to recompute the above test statistic with this new data. I am not sure how to do this.

And second, I want to the process above 1000 times, saving the test statistic
each time. I am also not sure how to do this. My inclination is to use a for loop, but I am not sure how to set it up. Any help would be really appreciated!

Comment: `orings` is from the `DAAG` package?  That's worth stating in your question: not everyone has access to it.  If it's small, maybe you should `dput()` it into your answer so that more people can help you...

Comment: Sorry about that. It is from the `faraway` package.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not completely clear what you're looking to do here, but we can at least show some quick principles of how we can achieve this, and then hopefully you can get to your goal.

## 1) Simulating the null model

It is not entirely clear that you would like to simulate the null model here. It seems more like you're interested in simulating the actual model fit. Note that the null model is the model with form `cbind(damage, 6-damage) ~ 1`, and the null deviance and df are from this model. Either way, we can simulate data from the model using the `simulate` function in base R.

```
sims <- simulate(orings_model, 1000)
```

If you want to go the manual way estimate the mean vector of your model and use this for the probabilities in your call to `rbinom`

```
nsim <- 1000 * nrow(orings)
probs <- predict(orings_model, type = 'response')
sims_man <- matrix(rbinom(nsim, 6, probs), 
                   ncol = 1000)
# Check they are equal:
# rowMeans(sims_man) - probs
```

In the first version we get a `data.frame` with 1000 `columns` each with a  `n` times `2` matrix (damage vs not damage). In the latter we just summon the `damage` outcome.

## 2) Perform the bootstrapping

You could do this manually with the data above.

```
# Data from simulate
statfun <- function(x){
  data <- orings_model$data
  data$damage <- if(length(dim(x)) > 1) 
    x[, 1] 
  else 
    x
  newmod <- update(orings_model, data = data)
  pchisq(newmod$null.deviance, newmod$df.null, lower=FALSE)
}
sapply(sims, statfun)

# data from manual method
apply(sims_man, 2, statfun)
```

or alternatively one could take a bit of time with the `boot` function, allowing for a standardized way to perform the bootstrap:

```
library(boot)
# See help("boot")
ran_gen <- function(data, mle){
  data$damage <- simulate(orings_model)[[1]][,1]
  data
}
boot_metric <- function(data, w){
  model <- glm(cbind(damage = damage, not_damage = 6 - damage) ~ temp, 
               family = binomial, data = data)
  pchisq(model$null.deviance, 
         model$df.null,
         lower=FALSE)
}
boots <- boot(orings, boot_metric, 
     R = 1000, 
     sim = 'parametric', 
     ran.gen = ran_gen, 
     mle = pchisq(orings_model$null.deviance, 
                  orings_model$df.null,
                  lower=FALSE))
```

At which point we have the statistic in `boots$t` and the null statistic in `boots$t0`, so a simple statistic can be estimated using `sum(boots$t > boots$t0) / boots$R` (R being the number of replication).